# Reduce snippet length in GSA results

Tags: google-search-appliance

I want to change the snippet(`<S>` in results xml) length , is it possible using front-end or some other way. Currently its returning long snippet, i want to reduce it as per new requirement. But this should not affect other collections and frontend in gsa, because GSA  box is serving lots of websites.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the res_snippet_size variable in the XSLT for your specific front-end?